# Adding new fonts like Verdana, Bookantiqua or Arial in fpdf documents

Tags: php, fpdf

How to add Verdana, Arial, Book Antiqua fonts in fpdf, please give some suggestion where to change and which file I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Use AddFont method.

```
AddFont(string family [, string style [, string file]])
```

See [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addfont.htm) or a [tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm).

Comment: which file i need to change?

Comment: In your own. Call it like $fpdf = new FPDF(); $fpdf->AddFont(...). There is even a [nice tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm)